# Best approach to login with AWS Cognito

Tags: authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito

What is the best approach to create login using AWS Cognito. App is using React/Angular frontend framework and is connected to Express Node server. I'm wondering how to create authentication using cognito/what is the safest way.

1. Create login endpoint on my REST API, send credentials to my server and from there connect to cognito and in response send tokens

Or

2. Make a direct connection from frontend to cognito and get tokens from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if there are not any specific requirements, better to go with option 2.

You should set up Cognito along with client application.

- Your front-end (FE) application makes user to authenticate via Cognito and receives an access token. It's used during communication with back-end (BE). In terms of OAuth2 your FE app is called **client app**.
- Your BE application receives request from your FE along with the access token. Access token should be verified against Cognito and should be processed accordingly. In terms of OAuth2 your BE app is called **resource server**.

For more details check the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-backend

Comment: Thanks, That's what I want to know

Answer (score 0):

I think that safest is to connect your frontend to an apigw (with a lambda), let the lambda connect to cognito and do the authorization, so you minimize the code written on the frontend. You can simply give the apigw url are redirect uri in the Cognito. There is not much documentation or examples online on this, but it is not hard to make. So both solutions are correct, but in terms of security, I'd prefer the first one.